# adult child qty field in magento store

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I m building one hotel booking site and i need to create functionality that display two qty box for adult and child respectively.so i have decided to create config product but it may need lengthy process.so i just want to add two qty field dynamically and manage product accordingly.so i can get adult and child qty in cart as well as in full order process.I have also attached image.[image][image]
So how can i achieve this.any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? What are you stuck with?

Comment: @Pekka웃 i want two qty field on product detial page.one for adult and one for child.so user can enter child parent and calculate price according in cart.

Comment: Hello you will create product attribute

Comment: yes you create product attribute for child[drop-down] and set different price for different count of child

Answer (score 0):

Create simple product with custom options.

Answer (score 0):

I use Mageworx Advanced Product Options for this.

It allows you to to specify quantity, pricing, images, and more for custom options.

Alternatively you can use Bundled products to accomplish this, by creating the simple products and linking them as a bundled option.

Example.

Bundle item = Europe Tour
Bundled with Simple Items
Simple item = Adult Ticket
Simple item = Child Ticket

This will result in a Europe Tour Product, with a choice for adult and child tickets, and different pricing. You could take this further to customize the Tour more so.